# Paste data into into correct date column in a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which is updated daily and a copy of that workbook is saved as that date. What I am looking to do is have a sheet with a column for each date of the year and save the data into the correct date column in order to have a daily record and a running total.

I used the IF function and it works great except when you change the date the previous column date is not saved. I think I will need a macro for this but don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is my code:

```
Sub KPI()

Dim lct As Long 
lct = Application.WorksheetsFunction.Match(Worksheets("KPI").Range("A1"), Worksheets("KPI").Range("H2:BP2"), 0) 

Worksheets("Shift Summary").Activate 
Range("F15").Select 

If Range("A4") = "I2" Then 

    Worksheets("KPI").Activate Cells(lct, 3).Select 
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ 
        :=False, Transpose:=False 

End If 

If Range("A4") = "J2" Then 

    Worksheets("KPI").Activate Cells(lct, 21).Select Selection.PasteSpecial         Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False 
End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: `but don't know where to start` - Try turning on the macro recorder and then manually doing what you want to do. After that, you can tweak the code to run more smoothly, by looking up some basic programming techniques in VBA ... `If Then Else` Loops - `Do While` `For Each Next` etc.

Comment: What i'm having difficulty with is writing the loops.

Comment: Please post the code that you are having difficulty with and tell us what you are trying to do with that code and what is not working. You can edit your post with this information.

Comment: =IF($A$1=H$2,IF('Shift Summary'!$A$4="I2",'Shift Summary'!$F13,0),0) I don't have any copies of what I tried to write in vba but this is the formula I tried to use which generates the right numbers but returns to zero when the date changes. A1 is the date generated from the data entry sheet, the dates in the table are in row 2, then there are 17 values to be taken from various sheets and pasted according to the correct "shift" that was working. All I need is a code for one row to place the data in the correct column based on the date, then I can figure out the IFs.

Comment: I suggest you write/record some more VBA code and post what you come up with if you get stuck. You could also post a screenshot or link to a file with your data structure. That will allow us to to help you much easier, than trying to interpret your comment text.

Comment: 'Sub KPI() Dim lct As Long lct = Application.WorksheetsFunction.Match(Worksheets("KPI").Range("A1"), Worksheets("KPI").Range("H2:BP2"), 0) Worksheets("Shift Summary").Activate Range("F15").Select If Range("A4") = "I2" Then Worksheets("KPI").Activate Cells(lct, 3).Select Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False End If If Range("A4") = "J2" Then Worksheets("KPI").Activate Cells(lct, 21).Select Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False End If End Sub'

Comment: and what is not working in this code, if anything?

Comment: Match won't work, is this because I'm using excel 2003? and activating a cell using the match result doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you please post either a link to a dummy file of your data? or a screenshot of the data. It's really hard to decipher your needs based on the text.

Comment: I'm sorry I've tried and followed the help but it won't let me post...

Comment: try now. I've just updated your rep points!

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\cpelchat\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.MSO\ExcelWebPagePreview\DUMMY HELP SHIFT Report - Coarse Tailings.htm

Comment: you do realize that I cannot access your hard drive, right? You can use a site like <https://www.dropbox.com/> to load your file, then send me a link for it.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94239292/DUMMY%20HELP%20SHIFT%20Report%20-%20Coarse%20Tailings.xls

Comment: okay, posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this code should you get you started.

I've named two ranges to the `Shift Summary` worksheet

`Date = Range("B1")`
`Safety = Range("F13:F22")`

The code below should give you a great start to get all the other elements you may need. There is probably more to add in terms of error-checking and such, but for now, this should get you well on your way.

```
Sub UpdateSummary()

Dim wksShift As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
Dim myDate As Date

Set wksShift = Sheets("Shift Summary")
myDate = wksShift.Range("Date")

Set wksSummary = Sheets("KPI")

With wksSummary

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = .Rows("2:2").Find(myDate, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas)

    If Not myRange Is Nothing Then 

        wksShift.Range("Safety").Copy

        myRange.Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much for being so patient :)